# Ubuntu 16.04 - Dark patch on monitor (disappears on reboot)

Tags: 16.04, xorg

This has been happening for a while. AFAICR, it didn't happen before I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

I will be using my computer for a while, and then I'll notice a dark patch that stays in the same location on my screen. It lloks like a 'burnt' patch on a CRT monitor.

The only way that I can get rid of it is to reboot the computer.

The location of the dark patch is in a slightly different location, and has a different size, each time it appears. It is always a rectangle.

I have never noticed which window was previously of that same size and in that same location.

I attach a screenshot - I didn't know until I looked at this screenshot whether the dark patch would appear on a screenshot. The dark patch in this screenshot appears superimposed over the text below the search text entry field.

While fiddling around switching between windows while getting and looking at the screenshot, and entering text here at AskUbuntu, I just noticed that the dark patch is no longer there, and I didn't have to reboot.

[image: Screenshot of dark patch]

Comment: Does the problem only occur in your web browser? Does it happen if you close all of your open tabs? Let me know. Cheers, Al

Comment: That is... strange...

Comment: I **think** it continues across all applications. It's not happening right now, so I can't check. I would rather check 100% than answer your questions from memory. I notice it most often in the browser, because that's when I am most likely to be looking at a large, white background, making this error more noticeable.

Comment: The answer is that it is nothing to do with the application. Just now, I noticed it in a browser, so I opened AskUbuntu to check the question, and then started another application (Ubuntu Software). The dark rectangle stayed on the screen while the application window opened. The dark rectangle does not move with application windows, and I haven't found any other way to affect it. It was there when I started writing this text, and I just noticed that it is not there right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further reflection, and due to something that I just did, I ***think*** this might be happening when I `Shift-PrtScr` to get a screenshot of something, and then navigate to another window (eg. having used `Copy to Clipboard` in order to then paste the screenshot into another application).

The dark rectangle represents the area that I captured in my screenshot in one application window, and it remains in the foreground on my monitor as long as the `PrtScr` window is still open.

That's what caused it to happen just now, anyway.

Comment: I was getting annoyed with this too until I saw this answer. Can confirm it happens when you take a screenshot of a part of your screen and you don't close the screenshot app (which happens easily when you select copy to clipboard and you then forget about it). After I closed the app the patch went away.